# JSON-RPC vs JSON

Tags: java, json, web-services

I am familiar with Restful services created using json as the medium. But today I heard a new term "JSON-RPC" which I am unfamiliar with.

On doing some research it looks as if JSON-RPC is similar to SOAP web services where you have a defined contract between the requestor and the responder and the requestor has to have a client in the form of a jar like I remember I used to have to do when I used Apache Axis SOAP web services (even though there would not be a wsdl).

So whilst it can be good if you want to enforce a really strong contract between two parties it can be cumbersome to change because you have to regenerate stubs and distribute stubs to any potential new requestors?

Have I summed it up correctly?

thanks

Comment: just to add more [info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056878/rest-vs-json-rpc)

Comment: So i was correct when I said that you need a client jar file to call a JSON-RPC restful web service?

Answer (score 0):

JSON-RPC is indeed similar to SOAP. It is just that normally you have no explicit contract and no service description file and the protocol is as simple as it gets.

This is what a JSON-RPC 1.0 request looks like: {"method": "echo", "params": ["Hello JSON-RPC"], "id": 1}